# Can I use electron forge to package an app with micro front end?

Tags: electron, electron-forge

I am trying to package an application that has two modules, one is a shell and the other contain the main feature of my application.

The app structure is the following one:

```
-->my app
    -->project
        -->shell
            -->src
        -->module
            -->src
```

The app use Angular and Electron, so Electron forge seemed like the best tool to package it.

However, after packaging, the .exe only start the shell of my application, and not the module.

So when I launch my app, I am able to navigate to the different part of the shell and it react as it is meant to, however when i try to use the feature, it does not react, as if the module did not exist.

I have tried to manually start the module on a terminal before using the .exe with a simple

```
ng serve module
```

When I do this, the shell become able to interact with the module and everything work.

I a pretty sure I could package the shell and the module as two separate application but it is not user friendly so it's not an option unless nothing else work.

Is it possible to have electron forge recognize my module and package it with the shell so I have everything in one app?

package.json:

```
{
  "name": "my-app",
  "productName": "test_packaging",
  "description": "My Electron application description",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "main": "main.js",
  "keywords": [],
  "author": {
    "name": "me",
    "email": "myEmail"
  },
  "license": "MIT",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "electron-forge start",
    "build": "ng build",
    "watch": "ng build --watch --configuration development",
    "run:all": "node node_modules/@angular-architects/module-federation/src/server/mf-dev-server.js",
    "start:electron": "electron .",
    "package": "electron-forge package",
    "make": "electron-forge make"
  },
  "config": {
    "forge": {
      "makers": [],
      "publishers": []
    }
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular-architects/module-federation": "^14.3.0",
    "@angular-material-components/color-picker": "^8.0.0",
    "@angular/animations": "~14.2.4",
    "@angular/cdk": "^14.2.3",
    "@angular/common": "~14.2.4",
    "@angular/compiler": "~14.2.4",
    "@angular/core": "~14.2.4",
    "@angular/elements": "^14.2.4",
    "@angular/forms": "~14.2.4",
    "@angular/material": "^14.2.3",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~14.2.4",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~14.2.4",
    "@angular/router": "~14.2.4",
    "@ngx-translate/core": "^14.0.0",
    "@ngx-translate/http-loader": "^7.0.0",
    "@types/crypto-js": "^4.1.0",
    "ajv": "^8.8.2",
    "crypto-js": "^4.1.1",
    "echarts": "^5.4.0",
    "electron-squirrel-startup": "^1.0.0",
    "file-saver": "^2.0.5",
    "ngx-build-plus": "^14.0.0",
    "ngx-color-picker": "^11.0.0",
    "ngx-echarts": "^8.0.1",
    "ngx-material-file-input": "^4.0.0",
    "ngx-socket-io": "^3.2.0",
    "ngx-translate-multi-http-loader": "^8.0.1",
    "rxjs": "~7.4.0",
    "socket.io-client": "^4.4.1",
    "tslib": "^2.3.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~14.2.4",
    "@angular/cli": "~14.2.4",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~14.2.4",
    "@electron-forge/cli": "^6.1.1",
    "@electron-forge/maker-deb": "^6.1.1",
    "@electron-forge/maker-rpm": "^6.1.1",
    "@electron-forge/maker-squirrel": "^6.1.1",
    "@electron-forge/maker-zip": "^6.1.1",
    "@types/file-saver": "^2.0.5",
    "@types/jasmine": "~3.10.0",
    "@types/node": "^12.11.1",
    "electron": "^23.1.1",
    "jasmine-core": "~3.10.0",
    "karma": "~6.3.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.0",
    "karma-coverage": "~2.0.3",
    "karma-jasmine": "~4.0.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "~1.7.0",
    "ngx-build-plus": "^14.0.0",
    "typescript": "~4.8.4",
    "zone.js": "^0.12.0"
  },
  "browser": {
    "crypto": false
  }
}
```

forge.config.json:

```
module.exports = {
  packagerConfig: {},
  rebuildConfig: {},
  makers: [
    {
      name: '@electron-forge/maker-squirrel',
      config: {
        name: "my_app"
      },
    },
    {
      name: '@electron-forge/maker-zip',
      platforms: ['darwin'],
    },
    {
      name: '@electron-forge/maker-deb',
      config: {},
    },
    {
      name: '@electron-forge/maker-rpm',
      config: {},
    },
  ],
};
```